# TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: "mouseWheel"; }' is not assignable to param of type 'MouseInputEvent | MouseWheelInputEvent | KeyboardInputEvent'

Tags: typescript, electron

I've put the `sendInputEvent` into `BrowserView` :

```
view.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'C'})
```

and in the `BrowserWindow` rendering page I've put:

```
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        console.log("App_S-keyDown-event: ", event)
    })
```

And it works with all keys, and arrows (up, down).

The issue is with `MouseWheelInputEvent` :  `type string - The type of the event, can be mouseWheel` : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/structures/mouse-wheel-input-event

If I put:

```
SearchWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'mouseWheel'})
```

I get this error message:

```
 TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: "mouseWheel"; }' is not assignable to parameter of 
type 'MouseInputEvent | MouseWheelInputEvent | KeyboardInputEvent'.
  Property 'keyCode' is missing in type '{ type: "mouseWheel"; }' but required in type
 'KeyboardInputEvent'.
```

It seems to be a `typescript`-`electron` issue

Other info:

```
electron: 19
typescript: ~4.5.4
O.S. : Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop
```

How to solve it?

Comment: `mousewheel` (not `mouseWheel`) is obsolete, use `wheel` per MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event)

Comment: @JayBuckman Yes. It was that problem. Substituting `mousewheel` with `wheel` it catches the wheel movements. If you put it as answer, I can flag it as correct solution. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues: First, it should be `mousewheel` not `mouseWheel`.  Second and more importantly for TypeScript, `mousewheel` is obsolete - you should use `wheel`.  See MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event).